# Can't install/run/uninstall any version of Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I've been getting a major error coming from Visual Studio.I was working on a project from Team Foundation and I simply closed my notebook, making it on stand by. when I opened it back, windows 8.1 loaded perfectly but the visual studio crashed. Now, when I open Visual Studio it loads and after a few seconds it crashes, frozen! I Can't uninstall, install other versions or anything!

I restarted my Windows (kept user files). No change. When I try to install it it crashes.

This is the only warning on the Log (devenv /Log)

```
  <entry>
    <record>37</record>
    <time>2015/07/18 22:02:22.994</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>The CTM file is out of date and should be deleted and rebuilt, but the file &apos;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\1033\devenv.CTM&apos; could not be deleted.</description>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Please post the log file for VS2013, so we'll be able to support your issue.
go to the location vs2013 is installed and open cmd, run Devenv /log Path\NameOfLogFile. the log will be located on the path with the selected file name.

Comment: When I Try to do it, Visual Studio Tries to open but it appears the error windows saying "The Operation could not be completed. No such interface supported"

Comment: Same problem here on win 10, but without any errors at all...

Answer (score 0):

I offer 2 method to overcome this issue:

> Try re-registering the actxprxy.dll and oleaut32.dll file in the
>   %SystemRoot%\system32 directory

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33dfdba4-4a11-4895-9554-0b2fd29e2578/visual-studio-2013-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-no-such-interface-supported?forum=vssetup

If first method didn't solve the issue:

Please go to Control Panel > Uninstall a program > Right click on the specified version of Visual Studio > Change. Then the uninstall menu for VS will come up and press Repair.

I hope it support your problem.

Comment: Sorry if I look noob, but how to I "re-register" it?

Comment: Ok, got it! But when I try to unregister the "oleaut32.dll" I the error message "The module 'oleaut32.dll' was loaded but the call to DllUnregisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005"

Comment: Now guess what... if I try to repair... the Visual Studio setup crashes!

Comment: Another curious thing: When the repair is about to run, it asks for the administrator rights, right after I click "Run" on those administrator warnings, the repair tool crashes.

If I disable this messages on configurations, it starts to repair, but I don't know if repairing it will fix the problem

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but no. The repair finished but no success. I open visual studio, it works fine for about 15 seconds and then it crashes

Comment: It looks like it's not a visual studio error, but a .net framework  error

Comment: How do you know its a .net framework error? have you tried to look in the event viewer --> windows --> application to see any logged issue from VS2013 side reporting its a .net framework issue?

Comment: This is an educated guess, can you try loading vs2013 while you disable the network adapter ( I mean by that to simulate no internet connection state) and get back with a report if vs2013 was running properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83368/discussion-between-frederico-novack-amaral-pereir-and-dejavo).